# Not able to update checked status of checkbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

On Click of add button I am adding new row using clone of last row but wants to uncheck checkbox if its already checked in last row.

Please check whole code on : http://jsfiddle.net/MMDZX/

Answer (score 2):

Change the broken line to:

```
jQuery("#dataTable tr:last").find("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked", false);
```

Two problems:

- You're searching on the wrong type of input element (`type=text` as opposed to `type=checkbox`).
- You're using a string and not a boolean to set the attribute, which would be fine if you were setting it to the checked state, since strings are truthy.

Also, `.children().children()` is unnecessary. `.find()`  (or [ancestor-descendant](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)) is much prettier in this case.

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/MMDZX/7/)

Answer (score 1):

See working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/3rLqV/

Changing the remove checked status line to:

```
jQuery("#dataTable tr:last input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr("checked");
```

Your two main problems were that you were looking for `type='text'`, instead of checkbox and you can't set `checked` to false. It's either there or not.

Comment: In jQuery 1.4.4, `.attr("checked",false)` will uncheck the checkbox because in 1.4.4 `.attr` modifies both the property and the attribute in this case. http://jsfiddle.net/MMDZX/17/ The real problem is he has it wrapped in quotes. `.removeAttr` is a good alternative though.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 // to add new row
        jQuery("#addRow").click(function () {
            var jqasdasuery = jQuery("#dataTable tr:last").clone();
            jqasdasuery.find('input[type=checkbox]').attr("checked", false);
            jQuery("#dataTable").append(jqasdasuery);
            setAttributes();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

`$(':checkbox',jqasdasuery).attr('checked', false);`

after the clone.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#addRow").on('click', function () {
                var jqasdasuery = $("#dataTable tr:last").clone();

                $("#dataTable tbody").append(jqasdasuery);
                $("#dataTable tr:last").find(':checkbox').attr('checked', false);
                $("#dataTable tr:last").find('select option:first').attr('selected', true); 
                setAttributes();
            });

            $("#deleteRow").on('click', function () {
                if ($("#dataTable tr").length === $("#dataTable input:checked").length) {
                    alert("You cant delete all the rows")
                } else {
                    $("#dataTable").find(':checked').each(function () {
                        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
                    });
                }

                setAttributes();
            });
        });

        function setAttributes() {
            $("#dataTable tr").each(function (i) {
                $(this).find(":checkbox").attr("name", "chk" + i);
                $(this).find(":text").attr("name", "txt" + i);
                $(this).find("select").attr("name", "country" + i);
            });

            //$("#dataTable tr:last").find("input[type='text']").attr("checked", "false");
        };
```

Comment: do not use $("#dataTable tr:last").find("input[type='text']").attr("checked", "false"); in setAttributes() function. because on delete last row will be unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

To remove checked status of checkbox when you clone last row.

You can add following line,

jqasdasuery.find("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked',false);

After

var jqasdasuery = jQuery("#dataTable tr:last").clone();

in  "#addRow" click function.